# problem with char arrays in network programming

Tags: c, arrays, networking, network-programming, char

I have the following:
nodeID = abcde.abc.edu_12345
and I need to append the an underscore and a 10digit value returned by time() to create the following:
node_inst_ID = abcde.abc.edu_12345_1016320007
where 1016320007 is the 10 digit value returned by time(). I am trying the following code but it doesnt seem to work:

```
#define NODE_ID_LENGTH 20
#define NODE_INST_ID 31
char nodeID[NODE_ID_LENGTH]
char node_inst_ID[NODE_INST_ID];
int main()
{
    /*
    Building of nodeID is a bit complex. So its hard to put all the code here. But printing the following at this point gives this
          for(int i = 0; i < NODE_ID_LENGTH; i++)
            {
              printf("%c", nodeID[i]);
            }
    gives
    abcde.abc.edu_12345
    If you need to know any more info about nodeID, I can post the print out of things that you suggest. 
    */

    long int seconds = time(NULL);
    char buf[10];
    sprintf(buf, "%ld", seconds);
    snprintf(&node_inst_ID[0], 20, "%s", &nodeID[0]);
    node_inst_ID[20] = '_';
    node_inst_ID[21] = '\0';
    cout<<"Node instance ID = "<<node_inst_ID<<endl;

    /* 
    I havent yet added the code for appending the time stamp. But I am expecting a print out for the above code like this:
    Node instance ID = abcde.abc.edu_12345_
    But the code is printing only
    Node instance ID = abcde.abc.edu_12345
    It is not adding the underscore at the end. 
    */
}
```

Can anyone point out what the mistake is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
snprintf(&node_inst_ID[0], 20, "%s", &nodeID[0]);
node_inst_ID[20] = '_';
node_inst_ID[21] = '\0';
```

This assumes that the string is exactly 20 characters long - it isn't. Try this:

```
snprintf(&node_inst_ID[0], 20, "%s", &nodeID[0]);
strcat(node_inst_ID, "_"); // strcat is safe in this context, usually you should use strncat.
```

EDIT: If you want to still use snprintf, the easy way is:

```
int len = strlen(node_inst_ID);
snprintf(node_inst_ID + len, sizeof(node_inst_ID) - len, "%whatever", the, args);
```

Comment: thanks. using strcat worked. Also, how do I print out the actual data in a char array? For e.g. I even want to print out that I have a '\0' at the end of the array. But if I use printf("%c", char_array[LIMIT]); it doesnt print out '\0'.

Comment: i could find something out by using %x in printf.  printf(%x, char_buf[i]); and incrementing i printed out 0 for '\0'

Answer (score 1):

You've hardwired the underscore to be at index 20 of node_inst_ID, however it only contains 18 characters and the null terminator at that point:

```
0123456789012345678
abcde.abc.edu_12345
```

Since you are not overwriting the null terminator, that's where the printout stops when you print the result. Don't assume positions and lengths for strings; instead, use string library functions to manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

`nodeID` is only 19 characters long. So it has a `\0` terminator in position 19, and so does the copy you make in `node_inst_ID`. Then you store some more stuff starting at position 20, *after the terminating zero-byte*. So your underscore is after the end of the string.